# How to overwrite a file inside a folder Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

There are parent and child theme inside the wordpress theme. I need to work on it for a client. When I logged on, the child theme was already selected. However, I need to modify a layout. The way it was set up is that in the parent theme's **`functions.php`**, there's a function that get all the files in the function folder

```
// Require all files in the function folder

function parent_theme_require_files() {

    $path = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/parent_theme/includes/functions/';

    foreach(glob($path.'*.php') as $file){
    require $file;
     }

}

parent_theme_require_files();
```

The function folder includes the folders for customizer, layouts, images, etc. The file I wanted to edit is inside the layouts folder. Inside the layouts folder, there are options for different layouts for header, footer, etc. And you can select the options right inside the **`Apperance -> Customize`** in the wordpress dashboard.

So how do I go about editing the layout header file in the child theme? The path for it is `"/themes/**parent_theme**/includes/layouts/header/header-1row-logo-phoneblurb.php"` and I want to somehow change it to `"/themes/**child_theme**/includes/layouts/header/header-1row-logo-phoneblurb.php"`

Comment: Try to check out the `Wordpress` `FileSystem API`. Lot's examples if you're search on google.

Comment: Just checked. I don't think that's the right one.